# Flex items are stretching

Tags: html, css

How do I avoid items in flex column stretching to full width? I want it to be original size as created.

```css
.myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Right not the inputs and the buttons have no width given. Just give them some width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max-width: max-content;`, or `width: max-content;` on child element.

```css
.myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
/* below will be select any first level children under .myForm */
.myForm > * {
    max-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `CSS` the default value for the flex property `align-items` is `stretch` which as you would guess stretches the children of the flex parent to full width. You can change it something else to fix that. For instance

```css
.myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
</form>
```

Read more about this property here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: Your answer is work very well but different approach from my. So, please don't edit something that is not related in my answer. I'll up vote for you because it's work and 100% flex CSS.

Comment: I know sorry, I was trying to edit mine, and somehow ended up editing yours

Comment: No problem :-) I've been mistake too.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned display:flex; so your elements size is also flexed to column size.
You can provide css property for your first level child individually like

```
.myForm > * {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```css
.myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
/* below will be select any first level children under .myForm */
.myForm > * {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
</form>
```